# ImageJ - Why Max, Min value change when I change Histogram Bins?

Tags: java, histogram, imagej

I'm using ImageJ to view Histogram of DICOM image.
When I show Histogram for the first time, I see `Min= -719`, `Max=1402`.
[image: histogram at the first time]

But when I press `Alt+H` to change Bins to 100. `Max`, `Min` value is change to 0 & 255.
I think when change bins then only `Bin Width` should change value, I don't know why `Max`, `Min`, `Count` value is changed.
You can download the DICOM image in this link: https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/CT%20Scan.dcm

[image: histogram after change bins to 100]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems when you focus on screen "Histogram of CT" and press `Alt+H` to change Bins, ImageJ will use the Histogram as a input image to draw Histogram.
That why you see `Count=72000` = `300x240` pixels in `Histogram of CT` screen.